# Lost with Rails has_many: through multiple search

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

Alright, I feel like I'm running in circles.

I have the following Rails models:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :image_tags
  has_many :tags, :through => :image_tags
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :image_tags
  has_many :images, :through => :image_tags
end

class ImageTag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :image
  belongs_to :tag
end
```

So basically I have Images, I have Tags, and images can have all sorts of tags.

If I want to find every image that has one tag, that is easy, right?

```
def Image.find_by_tag(t)
  includes('tags').where(['tags.name = ?', t]).references(:tags)
end
```

But I am pulling my hair out trying to figure out how to search for multiple tags simultaneously (I.e., to find all images that are e.g., both tagged as "funny" and "political").

`Image.find_by_tag('funny').find_by_tag('political')` always comes up with an empty set, even though there are multiple images that are tagged as both.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try with `in`:

```
def self.by_tags(t)
  includes('tags').where('tags.name in(?)', t.map(&:name)).references(:tags)
end
```

Note that it's necessary that the parameter `t` be an array containing objects that respond to `name` attribute.

Comment: Not sure about this, but if you'd use .collect(&:name) instead of map, t could also be an activerecord relation, right?